# Troubles rounding wordpress corners

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My current website is made with WordPress, and my theme is based on Twenty Eleven (default theme) which I just modify to meet my requirements. But I have one major problem. The corners of the **container** just wont round. Here's the [style.css](http://pastebin.com/JF7hCLtL) and here's a [live demo](http://abc.com).

How could I round the corners? I've only managed to round the banners corners...

Comment: They are rounded for me in Chrome.

Comment: Also a tip: border-radius has been unprefixed in Firefox since Firefox 4 in case you want to drop that. Firefox 3.6 is below 2% usage now.

Comment: It probably adds about 0.2kb to the total file size, so I'll just keep it there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I consulted a friend to help, I was told to use an invisible border around the page, so I did:

```
#page {
    margin: 2em auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
border:1px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
-webkit-border-radius:6px;-o-border-radius:6px;-moz-border-radius:6px;
}
```

Problem solved.